# What's the purpose of #_ in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I was going through a [library code](https://github.com/borkdude/babashka/blob/master/src/babashka/main.clj#L166) in which they used `#_`. As gone through multiple references, I understand `#_` is [discard symbol](https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters#_discard), which tell the reader to ignore whatever comes next.

Why it is even needed in the first place? If we have something to be ignored, why can't we remove it or just comment it? What's the significance of `#_` over commenting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's super handy when debugging or writing some altered code.

Say you have some massive function, and you want to comment it out for a  bit. You have a few options:

You can use line comments:

```
; (defn some-huge-thing []
;    ... Many lines)
```

But that's painful unless your IDE has an commenting shortcut, and even then it takes some work. Plus, I've found most IDE's handling of comment-shortcuts to work less than ideally. Sometimes they just add another "layer" of comments instead of removing the existing ones. Line comments also don't help if you only want to comment out a small piece of a function since they aren't context sensitive.

You could use [comment](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/comment):

```
(comment 
  (defn some-huge-thing []
      ... Many lines))
```

But I personally don't like `comment` because here, it requires either nesting the entire thing, or violating Parinfer just to add the comment. Also as @amalloy points out, it ends up expanding to `nil`, so it can only be used in a context where a stray `nil` won't effect anything.

... Or, you can use `#_`:

```
#_
(defn some-huge-thing []
    ... Many lines)
```

It doesn't require altering the function at all. It's just two keystrokes to put in, and two to remove. It also doesn't evaluate to `nil`; it's simply ignored. That means you can use it, for example, to comment out arguments inside of a function call.

I personally use `#_` quite often when playing around with different implementations and when I'm trying to isolate a bug. It causes anything comming immediately after it to be ignored, so it's very easy to control what is and isn't executing.

Comment: The bigger problem with `(comment ...)` is that it expands to nil, rather than expanding to nothing at all. So it doesn't work in the middle of a form.

Comment: @amalloy That's true. I actually use it so rarely I forgot about that limitation. Edited.

Comment: I nearly always use technique #1 (line commenting, CRTL-/ in Cursive), since both the `comment` macro and the `#_` trick both require well-formed expressions (balanced parens, etc), which I often don't have when I'm only partly finished with a code fragment.

Comment: @AlanThompson FWIW that's less of a problem if you use structural editing like paredit. I almost never have a malformed expression, even when it's not finished yet. To be fair though, if you have good structural editing support, you probably also have good comment-many-lines support, so whatever works.

Comment: Ya, I always use parinfer. I never have non-matching braces. I only turn parinfer off when I'm golfing because parinfer can cause weird things to happen when trying to remove whitespace.

Comment: What does "expands to nil" mean?

Comment: @Blaze The macro evaluates to the value `nil`. If the macro were an ordinary function, you'd say that it "returns `nil`".